# Polynomial interpolation- numerical analysis

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

Using polynomial interpolation show that the polynomials $p(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x+1) $and $f(x) = x^3 - 2x^2 - x + 2$ are one and the same......its absurdly simple...... I tried to show by Newtonian interpolation error that $p(x) - f(x) = 0$ yet I repeatedly get $p(x) - f(x) = f(x)$

Comment: Can you please show us how you compute the interpolation error?

Comment: How are they the same?  They are both cubic polynomials and they are certainly not equal.  $p(x) = (x - 1)(x + 1)(x - 2) = x^2 - 2x^2 - x + 2$.

Comment: F(x) - p(x) = (x-1)(x+1)(x-2)*f[x,1,-1,2] any mistake ?

Comment: @jared am really thankful you pointed out that it was a minor typing error

Comment: @ArnavDas But then isn't that the answer??

Comment: One more question unrelated to it : actually how do we type like that in the question I mean to say writing x^2 as really x raised to power of 2 format..?

Comment: Use [latex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (pronounced "lateck" or "lah-teck"), $x^2$ = `$x^2$`.

Comment: @jared yeah but how do we prove it using polynomial interpolation....

Comment: @ArnavDas I don't know what you mean by "prove it by polynomial interpolation", the two polynomials are equivalent because when you multiply out $(x-1)(x-2)(x + 1)$ it equals the polynomial $x^2 -2x^2 - x + 2$.  I don't see how polynomial interpolation could prove anything except that the two are _approximately_ equal on some interval--it certainly cannot prove two things are the same.

Comment: Well its something from numerical analysis